# Drupal Commerce Bundle batch import

Tags: commerce

Is there a way to create a batch import of product bundles, or an API function? I have a few hundred combinations of product type 1 & product type 2, with different amounts of each product type, depending on a bunch of factors. I have the Commerce Feeds module enabled, if that helps.

Comment: Do you mean batch create products?

Comment: I mean bundles of products (http://drupal.org/project/commerce_product_bundle)